# Enumerating all possible scenarios

Tags: python, combinatorics

I am trying to find all of the possible combinations for a set. Suppose I have 2 vehicles (A and B) and I want to use them by sending them and then return. Send and return are two distinct actions, and I want to enumerate all of the possible sequences of sending and returning this vehicle. Thus the set is [ A, A, B, B]. I use this code to enumerate:

```
from itertools import permutations 

a = permutations(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']) 
   
# Print the permutations
seq = []
for i in list(a):
    seq.append(i)
seq = list(set(seq)) # remove duplicates
```

The result is as follows:

```
('A', 'B', 'B', 'A')
('A', 'B', 'A', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
('B', 'A', 'B', 'A')
('B', 'B', 'A', 'A')
('B', 'A', 'A', 'B')
```

Suppose my assumption is the two vehicles identical. Thus, it doesn't matter which one is on the first order (i.e. ABBA is the same as BAAB). Here's what I expect the result is:

```
 ('A', 'B', 'B', 'A')
 ('A', 'B', 'A', 'B')
 ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
```

I can do this easily by removing the last three elements. However, I encounter a problem when I try to do the same thing for three vehicles ( a = permutations(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']). How to ensure that the result already considers the three identical vehicles?

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you want to handle `A` and `B` as if they were identical?  And if `C` is added, it should also be handled as it was identical to `A`?

Comment: Yes, I want to treat them as identical. So, vehicle A, B, C is also identical

Comment: One way would be to generate all the combinations, then filter for only those where the *first mention of each vehicle* is in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to generate all the combinations, then filter for only those where the *first mention of each vehicle* is in alphabetical order.

In recent versions of Python, `dict` retains first-insertion order, so we can use it to determine the first mention; something like:

```
from itertools import permutations 

seq = set()
for i in permutations(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']):
    first_mentions = {car: None for car in i}.keys()
    if list(first_mentions) == sorted(first_mentions):
        seq.add(i)
```

(This works in practice since Python 3.5, and officially since Python 3.7)

Answer (score 1):

```html
from itertools import permutations 

a = permutations(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']) 
   
seq = []
for i in list(a):
    if i[0]=='A':
        seq.append(i)
seq = list(set(seq))
print(seq)
```

Try this, I think this should do

Comment: That won't work for the three-vehicle case, though?